# Retrieve Import Alerts published by FDA

Tags: api, openfda

The FDA publishes lists of Import Alerts in HTML format, such as, for example, on this [page](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cms_ia/importalert_259.html). This is in FDA site under Industry > Import > Program Actions & Enforcement > Import Alerts.

This data is not structured to be processed by software.
I am looking for a way (API, web service...) to retrieve these lists in a format that can be processed (JSON, XML, whatever). I found the OpenFDA (https://open.fda.gov/) site, but it looks like the Import Alerts are not published here.

Does anyone know of an alternative source of info for FDA publications or something specific for Import Alerts?

Comment: that document's source is a thing of nightmares.